# YUI autocomplete with yahoo finance api http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com

Tags: autocomplete, yui

i am having an issue with YUI autocomplete, i hope any one can please give a hand, it has been really frustrating, to be honest, i am new to YUI and i have been working on this for some time, and still unable to figure out the crux....

I would really appreciate it if anyone could please kindly help.

The following is my problem description.

I would like to use YUI autocomplete to display the content in the drop-down list generated from the following web service

```
http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=yhoo&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback
```

This webservice is returning a JSONP.
So everytime i enter a char in the input field, my autocomplete will be supposed to display a list of relevant names, the query term "query=yhoo" in this case; I have been investigating the YUI autocomplete with JSONP, but the confusion is that the autocomplete example with JSONP given in YUI website is not containing a fixed callback as shown above.

In the YUI autocomplete example, they are using the jsonp url where the callback part is not being explicitly present. But the above url i am using has a fixed callback part in itself, i cannot eliminate it; if i eliminated it, i would encounter 404 error;

As mentioned in the YUI website, i probably have to specify url with `callback={callback}`, but in my case, i cannot do that because that url already has a fixed callback.

Any kind help will be appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I would like to further clarify my problem, i would like to please understand how to get the YUI autocomplete to work with the following jsonp url http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=yhoo&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's a public API that you can use. My recommendation is that you use **YQL** instead:

1. Go to the YQL Console [[link](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)]
2. Select "Show community tables" on the left
3. Expand the "Yahoo" option and you'll see all the available Finance APIs

From YUI you can even use `Y.YQL` which will handle the JSONP side by itself and let you write the YQL query as an SQL query in your code. See http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yql/.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing your thoughts, i want that out with using data source. This is a bit tricky actually...

Comment: You can use `DataSource.Get` with the URL that you get from the YQL Console.